# cant read a text file with python

Tags: python, file

so guys i just copied a couple of paragraph into a text file (test.txt) and ran this

```
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
   print(f.read())
```

and i got this

```
 return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 1588: character maps to <undefined>
```

i dont know what that error means , i dont know why it wont work ,its just a simple code , so can someone explain what is the problem in simple words. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try add encoding in the open statement:

```
with open('test.txt','r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
   print(f.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this has occurred on Windows when trying to read a file with emojis

Try reading the raw binary form of the file as such:

```
with open('text3.txt', 'rb') as f:
    print(f.read())
```